# Executing script that was dynamically injected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm loading some html from an external [trusted] source using an XHR. This script is then injected into a div element using the innerHTML property. Followed by this, I use getElementsByTagName('script') to identify all the script tags in this newly loaded html and execute them sequentially via eval.
This practice seems to work for the most part, except it intermittently breaks (on Chrome) with an error originating from one of these script tags.
My only guess is that the order of elements returned by getElementsByTagName is not guaranteed but I could not find any evidence to support this.
An important thing to note is that the content is often refreshed by setting innerHTML to an empty string and repeating the process.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

**Update:** seems like these scripts are polluting the global namespace (window) and thus when content is refreshed they may trigger an error. Not sure how to work around this other than using iframes.

Comment: Have you tested your theory? You could add IDs to the script tags and look them up sequentially.

Comment: are you correctly using your code on completion of the XHR?Could be possible its not returned as HTML when its showing the error.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName the elements are indeed "in the order they appear in the sub-tree". So I don't think it's a matter of the order.